# i used nullif and got sql divide by zero error

Tags: sql-server, divide-by-zero

```
select STORECODE,
   ItemCode,
   ColorCode,
   ToplamStok,
   ToplamSatis,
   (CASE WHEN ToplamSatis = 0
     THEN ISNULL(ToplamStok/NULLIF(ToplamSatis,0.1)*7,0)
        ELSE (ToplamStok/ToplamSatis)*7
        end) as SDH
   into #SatisStokSDH
   from #SatisStok
```

for this query, I'm getting this error : Divide by zero error encountered.
why am i getting this, i already used isnull function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: because you are still dividing by zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when `ToplamSatis` happens to be zero, you are still dividing by zero:

```
NULLIF(ToplamSatis, 0.1)
```

The above would replace `ToplamSatis` with `0.1`, but only if the former were `NULL`, *not* if it were zero.  Try the following `CASE` logic:

```
CASE WHEN ToplamSatis = 0
     THEN ISNULL((ToplamStok / 0.1)*7, 0)   -- not sure if need to wrap with ISNULL
     ELSE (ToplamStok / ToplamSatis)*7
END
```

Comment: Tim,I tried the query that you have shared above and it works now, thanks!